# Grouping counted values of Multidemsional arrays

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, counting

I am attempting to not only count the amount of times a certain value appears in an array, but also limit the output to only even results.

```
    $quotes = array(
      array(
        'quote' => 1,
        'from' => 'NC',
      ),
      array(
        'quote' => 2,
        'from' => 'MA',
      ),
      array(
        'quote' => 3,
        'from' => 'OH',
      ),
      array(
        'quote' => 2,
        'from' => 'MA',
      ),
      array(
        'quote' => 1,
        'from' => 'NC',
      ),  
    );
```

How can I filter through this array to count the amount of times each 'quote' and then display the results where the count > 1.

Comment: each unique 'quote' shows an even amount of times - what do you mean?

Comment: @Raidenance, to filter this array to only duplicate values.  in this case only 1 should be displayed and 2 & 3 ignored since they are only appearing once

Comment: did you already try my solution?

Comment: @michi, not yet, was away from my work pc. I will try today and let you know, looks good though.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$result = array_map('unserialize',array_keys(array_diff(array_count_values(array_map('serialize',$quotes)),array(1))));
```

How it works:

1. make a one-dimensional-array by `serialize`
2. count all values
3. delete all values that count `1` using `array_diff`
4. as `array_count_values` put value into key, retrieve keys as values
5. `unserialize` to put it back into original design

see it working: http://codepad.viper-7.com/9RPjdK

Comment: This works great, one question though.
can this be set to filter only if 'quote' is duplicate?

I will input more data in each array which might mess with that line of filtering.